# How to get data from notification when receiving push for android (firebase)?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

I am sending a message of this kind on android

```
{
    "to": "dmi38iyVcvs:APA91bEDaB1jmhwZzRq-Sk448FuYItqMtJkAtzfJVr2ECNB-3I2HiBcadukMHsez7BxtbUEUHOddJzQccbNTgVu6Ay3QVqa3lEGhUqaT6rwee45x9sCtB_YVlxM9pl56ryahUU346Rw8",
    "data": {
        "title": "trtr",
        "message": "trtr",
        "deeplink": "https://webview/google.com"
    }
}
```

And parse in FirebaseMessagingService But without field "notification" in iOS push not working (with field "notification" all OK)

With field "notification" i cannot get data from push on android

I am reading the official docking firebase but cannot find the answer

This parsing data

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        remoteMessage?.data?.let {
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString(TITLE, it[TITLE])
            bundle.putString(MESSAGE, it[MESSAGE])
            bundle.putString(LINK, it[LINK])

            createNotificationChannel()
            sendNotification(bundle)
        } ?: run {
            Timber.v("received null")
            return
        }
    }
```

Then I tried to leave both the notification field and the data field

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Object data = getIntent().getData() //Not working (data = null)
}
```

How can I leave both fields (notification and data) and get data from the "date" field in android?

It’s difficult for me to describe the question more clearly, therefore I will answer all your clarifying questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more time I solved this problem

In my Manifest.xlm I added this

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

(for my MainActivity)

In MainActivity in method onCreate added

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
Uri deepLinkUri = null;
if (data.containsKey("deeplink"))
deepLinkUri = Uri.parse(intent.getExtras().getString("deeplink"));
```

And POST JSON

```
{
    "to": "dmi38i.....yVVvs",
    "data": {
        "deeplink": "app://webview/google.com"
    },
    "notification": {
        "title": "test_notification",
        "body": "test_notification",
        "click_action" : "VIEW"
    },
    "priority": "high"
}
```

(Added `"click_action" : "VIEW"` to `notification`)

I hope this helps someone

Comment: Have you been able to make the device also play sound while using this structure?